# Экспорт текста из RichEdit в MS Word в виде таблицы

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, ms-word, delphi-2010

Как экспортировать текст содержащийся в компонентах формы Delphi `RichEdit1` и `RichEdit2` в MS Word 2007 в таблицу из двух столбцов?

Comment: По данной ссылке находится совершенно другой пример - создание отчета по простому шаблону. Там даже рамки и двух столбцов у таблицы нет.

Comment: у меня мой проект работал отлично на дельфи7, а после того как перенес на дельфи 2010 ругается за несовпадение типов. Абсолютно тот же код.

Comment: _дельфи 2010 ругается за несовпадение типов._ Ну так покажите какие ошибки выдает Delphi 2010. На что конкретно ругается?

Answer (score 1):

Управление Word-ом осуществляется через OLE
Читаем подробнее [ТУТ](http://www.delphi.int.ru/articles/11/)
"Часть 4. Работа с таблицами"

Там описывается, как пользоваться OLE. А для таблиц будет что-то вроде

```
WordDocument1.Tables.Add(WordDocument1.Range, i, j, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
```